# What does the (?) mean when using ls utility?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards

I am using the *ls* utility and my command looks like this:

```
$ ls x?[a-c]*
```

What is the output of such command? So far I understand (and I hope it's right) that it will list items that:

- start with x
- third letter is {a,b,c}
- anything after third letter, does not matter, is included

**My question** is, what does the **?** (question mark) represent? What condition is it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You seem to have groked it. Except that it is bash not ls that is evaluating the pattern. Therefore you can use in in any command (not just `ls`).

Comment: On most systems, it would only be _{a,b,c}_ in the `C`/`POSIX` locale. For instance, in a `en_US.UTF-8` locale on a GNU system (with glibc 2.23), `[a-c]` in `bash` matches on `ABabcªÀÁÂÃÄÅÆàáâãäåæĀāĂăĄąƁǍǎǞǟǠǡǢǣǺǻǼǽȀȁȂȃȦȧɓḀḁḂḃḄḅḆḇẚẠạẢảẤấẦầẨẩẪẫẬậẮắẰằẲẳẴẵẶặ`. You'd need `[abc]` to match on `a`, `b` or `c` only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not an `ls` feature, it's a `bash` feature and it's described in the
“Pattern Matching” section in [bash(1)](https://man.cx/bash):

> The special pattern characters have the following meanings:
>
> **`*`**
>
>     Matches any string, including the null string.  When the
>     **`globstar`**
>     shell option is enabled, and
>     **`*`**
>     is used in a pathname expansion context, two adjacent
>     **`*`**
>     s used as a single pattern will match
>                            all  files  and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If followed by a
>     **`/`**
>     , two adjacent
>     **`*`**
>     s will match only directories and subdirectories.
>
> **`?`**
>
>     Matches any single character.
>
> **`[...]`**
>
>     Matches any one of the enclosed characters.  A  pair  of  characters  separated  by  a  hyphen
>                            denotes  a
>     *range expression*
>     ; any character that falls between those two characters, inclusive,
>                            using the current locale's collating sequence and character set, is  matched.   If  the  first
>                            character  following  the
>     **`[`**
>     is  a
>     **`!`**
>     or a
>     **`^`**
>     then any character not enclosed is matched.  The
>                            sorting order of characters in range expressions is determined by the current locale  and  the
>                            values  of the
>     **`LC_COLLATE`**
>     or
>     **`LC_ALL`**
>     shell variables,
>       if set.  To obtain the traditional interpretation of range expressions,
>       where
>     **`[a-d]`**
>     is equivalent to
>     **`[abcd]`**
>     , set value of  the
>     **`LC_ALL`**
>     shell  variable  to
>     **`C`**
>     ,  or  enable  the
>     **`globasciiranges`**
>     shell option.  A
>     **`-`**
>     may be matched by
>                            including it as the first or last character in the set.  A
>     **`]`**
>     may be matched by including it as
>                            the first character in the set.

Your understanding is also not entirely correct – `?` means any single
character, so the expression `x?[a-c]*` would match `xQcFoo.bar`, `xmabc` and `x1a`but also `xabc` - the point is that `{a,b,c}` may be also the second letter, not only the third. Output of `ls x?[a-c]*` command will be a list of files that match
`x?[a-c]*` pattern. Or, if there are no such files, the shell won't substitute `x?[a-c]*` with anything, so `ls` will try to list the file literally named `x?[a-c]*`.

Comment: Also note that if any of those files are of type _directory_, it will list their content. Generally, you want to use the `-d` option when you pass globs to `ls`. Also not that if there's no matching file, in `bash`, and unless the `nullglob` or `failglob` options are enabled, `x?[a-c]*` will be passed verbatim  to `ls`. And if that file exists, it will be listed (even though it doesn't match the pattern). If not, `ls` (not the shell) will report an error.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: If you're not trying to list contents, why use `ls` at all?  Just use `echo`, unless you're also passing `-l` or something else that gets you additional information.

Comment: @Kevin, yes, exactly, people use `ls *.txt` thinking `ls` is listing the `*.txt` files, while it's actually the shell that does the listing and `ls` is only doing the displays, and also things that were not asked for (like listing the content of directories or interpreting file names that start with `-` as options). You'd need `ls -d -- *.txt`, and the only reason why you'd want that over `printf '%s\n' *.txt` (remember `echo` can't be used for arbitrary data) is to work around he problem that some shells leave globs unexpanded when they don't match. And that `printf` still outputs (tbc)

Comment: (continue) when there's no argument to satisfy the formant (you don't have this problem with csh, tcsh, fish, zsh...)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: use-case: In most people's default setup, `ls` does colour highlighting to show you if any of your `*.txt` files are symlinks.  Of course it's also faster to type than `printf '%s\n' *.txt`, and formats the listing into columns.  The text processing could be done a different way, but wouldn't highlight symlinks (or files with their `x` bit set, which sometimes happens when they're from another system.)

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk: (1) What’s wrong with the OP’s interpretation of the wildcard? (2) Why are you giving example filenames that include the string `abc`?  You realize that `[abc]` matches *any **one*** of the letters `a`, `b` and `c` (and `[a-c]` matches any one letter in that range; see [Stéphane Chazelas’s comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/450300/80216#comment817459_450300)), right?  Examples like `xabc` and `xmabc` are confusing.  (Consider, for example, `x1a` and `xQcFoo.bar` instead.)

Comment: @G-Man: 1. OP said that the third letter is `{a,b,c}` but the second letter
specified by `?` can also be `{a,b,c}`, not only the third.  Although
looking at that now I admit that this part of my answer deserves an
additional comment 2. Thank you for the examples, I will edit my answer
in a few hours.